# Eliminate overwriting of files

Tags: php, image, upload, rackspace

I have the following code which uploads images to a rackspace cdn account.

```
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

                    // include the API
                    require("cloudfiles.php") ;

                    // cloud info
                    $username = ''; // username
                    $key ='' ; // api key
                    $container = ''; // container name

                    ob_start();


                    $localfile = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
                    $filename = $_FILES['media']['name'];



                    ob_flush();

                    // Connect to Rackspace
                    $auth = new CF_Authentication($username, $key);
                    $auth->authenticate();
                    $conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

                    // Get the container we want to use
                    $container = $conn->create_container($container);

                    // store file information

                    ob_flush();

                    // upload file to Rackspace
                    $object = $container->create_object($filename);
                    $object->load_from_filename($localfile);

                    $uri = $container->make_public();
                    //print "Your URL is: " . $object->public_uri();

                    $imagePageUrl = $object->public_uri();

                    //echo '<mediaurl>' . $imagePageUrl . '</mediaurl>';


                    ob_end_flush();


                    //echo '<mediaurl>' . $imagePageUrl . '</mediaurl>';

                    echo '<mediaurl>http://url.com/'.$filename.'</mediaurl>';
```

So each time i am uploading an image, say, image.jpg, it is overwriting the previous image.jpg in the container. I want to prevent that. Even if the filename is the same, is there a way to convert the filename to a random name, characters and then upload it?

Help plz.

Comment: Is it just me or does it look like there's code missing from that example?

Comment: There is a lot of code missing but it doesn't matter. I only need to change the filename to something else (unique)

Comment: Then do something like `$filename .= time()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ... some code is missing ...
 but you can try to give the new filename  (uploaded image)... one name that is unique
simple example:

```
 $filename = time()."-".$_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
```

like this way your images will be named like '1333221458-my_image.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

Reading the other answers, while `time()` approach seems good, it does not provide real unique ids, its accuracy is only 1 second.

But PHP provides a way for having real [unique IDS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) which is more accurate and provide a better solution. You could use it like:

```
$filename=uniqid().$_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
```

Of course changing `$_FILES['media']['tmp_name']` for whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this one too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the time to the filename, so assuming you will always have a .jpg:

```
$filename=explode(".",$filename);
$filename[0].="_".time();
$filename=implode(".",$filename);
```

Comment: It is now displaying in this format. /image.jpg1333221708. Is there a way to add the time before the image? Like this: 1333221708-image.jpg

Comment: Yes, based upon how you manipulate the text concatenation. After the `explode()`, `$filename[0]` should be "image" and `$filename[1]` is "jpg". To accomplish what you seek change the middle line of code to `$filename[0]=time()."-".$filename[0];`